# Opencart's Extension Installer error

Tags: opencart2.x

Opencart doesn't install extensions (modules) via Extension installer in admin panel. 
Error:

> Directory containing files to be uploaded could not be found

Version: opencart 2.3.0.2

FTP: enabled, all settings are ok.
Local copy OCMOD (Quick Fix) installed

I found nothing in Google.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the routes on `/admin/config.php` and try setting full directory routes.